# Bigquery error Origin and Referer header don't match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, request, referer

A quick question about Bigquery.

May you please advice me what to do when I got the error like :

Bad request: Origin and Referer header don't match.

Origin: https://clients6.google.com

Referer: https://console.cloud.google.com

Tracking number: c298544436245353

I just start to take google BA course and get to learn how to use SQL, however, when I follow the instruction to upload the table into the database, it always failed.

Thanks for helping me.

[image: 1]

This is what I got.

Comment: sounds like the table already exists, try to delete it and repeat the process

Comment: Have you enabled [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/create-billing-account#about-cloud-billing-accounts) in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same bug today. My solution was to change my browser from Brave to Chrome. After that, this error went away.